# How to access the context of imported modules in ES6?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I might have my terminology mixed up, but in the same manner that I can access the global context through `window`, I would like to access the current context of my imported modules.

To give a simple example of what I'm doing, imagine we have a file called `MyClasses.js` which contains the following two classes:

```
export class MyClass1 {}
export class MyClass2 {}
```

Then we import said classes into a file called `main.js`

```
import {MyClass1, MyClass2} from './MyClasses'
```

In `main.js` I might construct a new instance of each class based on some property value.

```
function main()
{
    const config = { case1: 'MyClass1', case2: 'MyClass2', case3: 'MyClass1' };

    const myPropValue = 'case3';
    const constructorName = config[myPropValue];
    const myClass = new context[constructorName](); // MyClass1
}
```

This is a basic example, but in a situation where there are many classes and cases for constructing such classes, I'd like to map the relationship rather than depend on intricate if/else logic.

One solution would be to attach the imported classes to the `window` context...

```
window.MyClass1 = MyClass1;
window.MyClass2 = MyClass2;
```

... and construct instances of my classes from there:

```
const myClass = new window[constructorName](); // valid construction
```

But I'd like to avoid binding these to the global scope. Is there a default context for any imported modules, or do I need to set up a context myself?

Comment: Instead of putting the names (as strings) in there, why not just lookup the class (constructor function) itself? `config = { case1: MyClass1, case2: MyClass2, case3: MyClass1 }`

Comment: @Bergi Yes, this is a better solution. Not sure why I didn't think of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify your import and you will be ok:

```
import * as MyClasses from './MyClasses';
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this is not called "context", but a *module namespace object*.